# Get list of packages to be installed from script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, apt-get

On Ubuntu 12.04 it is possible to do

```
k=0
if apt-get --assume-no upgrade | grep -q linux-; then
   k=1
fi

aptitude -y safe-upgrade

if [ $k == 1 ]; then
   /sbin/reboot
fi
```

but on older versions, `apt-get` doesn't have `--assume-no`.

**Question**

Is there another way to get the list of packages that are going to be installed?

Comment: Have you tried `--dry-run` (or `-s`)? According to the man page: _No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system._

Comment: On another level: if your goal is to determine whether you need a reboot, consider using `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required` or do what this script does: check whether the file `/var/run/reboot-required` exists.

Comment: `-s` works perfectly =)

Comment: Transformed that into an answer... and my message about not parsing `apt-get` but using `/var/run/reboot-required` is serious `;)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `--dry-run` (or `-s`)? According to the man page:

> No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system.

On another level: if your goal is to determine whether you need a reboot, consider using the script `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required` or do what this script does: check whether the file `/var/run/reboot-required` exists.